# Aws Serverless deployment - TypeError: Object.values is not a function in the serverless deploy command to aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, split-stacks

I was trying to redeploy an updated serverless function to an existing cloud formation stack on AWS using both Jenkins Job as well as manually.

Tried to create a new cloud formation stack and also tried to rebuild the previous successful build using Jenkins CI. The node version on AWS is nodejs10.x,
The error is coming when using the sls deploy function
Also tried to get support from the github repository for serverless-plugin-split-stacks

```sh
$ sls deploy
```

THe following the the error messaging that was being faced

```
Serverless: Invoke aws:package:finalize

  Type Error ---------------------------------------------

  Object.values is not a function

     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.

  Stack Trace --------------------------------------------

TypeError: Object.values is not a function
    at ServerlessPluginSplitStacks.logSummary (c:\jenkins\workspace\Deploy-DeviceCloudServices\api\dist\deployment\node_modules\serverless-plugin-split-stacks\lib\log-summary.js:7:27)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then.then.then.then.then (c:\jenkins\workspace\Deploy-DeviceCloudServices\api\dist\deployment\node_modules\serverless-plugin-split-stacks\split-stacks.js:67:24)
From previous event:
    at PluginManager.invoke (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:368:22)
    at PluginManager.spawn (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:386:17)
    at AwsPackage.BbPromise.bind.then (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\plugins\aws\package\index.js:69:51)
From previous event:
    at Object.package:finalize [as hook] (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\plugins\aws\package\index.js:69:10)
    at BbPromise.reduce (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:368:55)
From previous event:
    at PluginManager.invoke (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:368:22)
    at PluginManager.spawn (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:386:17)
    at Deploy.BbPromise.bind.then.then (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\plugins\deploy\deploy.js:123:50)
From previous event:
    at Object.before:deploy:deploy [as hook] (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\plugins\deploy\deploy.js:113:10)
    at BbPromise.reduce (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:368:55)
From previous event:
    at PluginManager.invoke (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:368:22)
    at PluginManager.run (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:399:17)
    at variables.populateService.then (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\Serverless.js:102:33)
    at runCallback (timers.js:637:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:582:5)
From previous event:
    at Serverless.run (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\Serverless.js:89:74)
    at serverless.init.then (C:\Users\builder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\bin\serverless:42:50)
```